# Set the Touch-Key Light Duration

Tags: java, android, settings, key

I would like to know whether (and how) it is possible to set the light duration of the touch-keys in Android (Back, Menu)

Could someone please tell me how to do that, preferably system-wide and not only in my app?

Thanks for your help!